# "param is missing or the value is empty: todo" (issue with strong parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

There are similar questions, but after 18h of reading them and several guides trying and trying I still haven't been able to solve my problem. That's why I'm posting this question. Thanks in advance!

Trying to POST data to create a new record but get *"param is missing or the value is empty: todo"*

FORM

```
<div class="addactionform">
  <%= form_for(Action.new, :url => { action: "create" }) do |todo| %>
    <div class="input-field"> <%= todo.text_field :title %> </div>
    <div class="hidden"> <%= todo.submit %> </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

ROUTE

```
root 'actions#inbox'
get '/actions' => 'actions#inbox'
post '/actions/create' => 'actions#create', as: :create
```

CONTROLLER

```
class ActionsController < ApplicationController

def inbox
    @todos = Action.all
end

def new
   @todo = Action.new
end

def create
    @todo = Action.new(todo_params)
    @todo.save    
    redirect_to(:action => 'inbox')
end

private
    def todo_params
       params.require(:todo).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

ACTION MODEL

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :tag, through: :action_tags
  belongs_to  :folder
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :state
end
```

MIGRATION

```
class CreateActions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :actions do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :note
      t.references :tags
      t.integer :assignee_id
      t.references :state
      t.datetime :due_at
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.references :folder
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I was finally able to solve the issue this way:

VIEW

```
<%= form_for Action.new, as: :todo do |action| %>
  <div class="input-field"><%= action.text_field :title %></div>
  <div class="hidden"><%= action.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
  def create
   @action = Action.create(action_params)
   redirect_to(:action => 'inbox')
  end

  private
    def action_params
       params.require(:todo).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

The part where I name the Action.new in VIEW as todo "as: :todo" is because my model is called Action and since Rails by default sends an :action param containing the action, I was returning the name of the action requested as a string.

Part of the solution is thanks to @guilherme-franco in the answer to the following. [Rails 4, strong parameters, nested resources, build and undefined method permit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210080/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-resources-build-and-undefined-method-permit)

Answer (score 0):

This line in your form

```
<%= form_for(Action.new, :url => { action: "create" }) do |todo| %>
```

should be like this

```
<%= form_for(@todo, :url => { action: "create" }) do |todo| %>
```

and your `todo_params` should be like this

```
def todo_params
   params.require(:action).permit(:title)
end
```

Comment: Tried it your suggestion Pavan, but now receive "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" for                             <%= form_for(@todo, :url => { action: "create" }) do |todo| %>

Comment: @sinakes What happens you didn't change that. I mean `Action.new` instead of `@todo`?

Comment: Now went back to
<%= form_for(Action.new, :url => { action: "create" }) do |todo| %> but kept 
   params.require(:action).permit(:title)

Results is that I get 
"undefined method `permit' for "create":String"  for            params.require(:action).permit(:title)

Comment: @sinakes try giving it like this `<%= form_for(Action.new) do |todo| %>`

Comment: Now get "No route matches [POST] "/actions"" (see my routes in my initial question. 

Because I got that I also tried to add a new route "post '/actions' => 'actions#create'" 

but again got "undefined method `permit' for "create":String". 

So I also tried removing "post '/actions/create' => 'actions#create', as: :create" . But the same error message again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a model named `Action` so Rails cannot map its name to `"todo"` parameters. I'm pretty sure that your code renders HTML input tags with name like `"action[title]"`. So `params.require(:todo).permit(:title)` cannot find `"todo"` inputs because they are named as `"action"`.

Try to use a symbol in `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for(:todo, url: actions_create_path) do |todo| %>
```

Or just use `:action` in `params.require` (like @Pavan said):

```
params.require(:action).permit(:title)
```